# DAO design pattern interface

Tags: design-patterns

Is this design pattern only good for one interface, cause all I can find is talking about interface implemented it by a class?

like the site
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/data_access_object_pattern.htm

If I have many interfaces the design pattern be good to use, and who the class diagram will be like?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Design patterns just supply you with solutions and abstraction, rather than restrict you to some concrete implementation. You can use the logic that suites you best and freely combine parts to achieve your goal.

Regarding

> Is this design pattern only good for one interface

You can consider one of SOLID principles - [Interface_segregation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) and still reuse the DAO pattern.

Hope this helps you.

- Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The use of the interface is to hide the implementation details,for this simple,the interface StudentDao can create/update/read/delete Student,Users don't have to know is how to implement these functions.
for a mysql database,maybe i have a MysqlStudentDao, and for a oracle database,i can implementation a OracleStudentDao, and some day ,if i want to use lucene,i even can have a LuceneStudentDao;but for the users,it just need to know,what i use is a StudentDao that has the functions:

```
public List<Student> getAllStudents();
public Student getStudent(int rollNo);
public void updateStudent(Student student);
public void deleteStudent(Student student);
```